# Entity Spaces - Save issues when using SQLServer session state

Tags: asp.net, session-state, entityspaces

We have been working with Entity Spaces and everything was working great on our local development machines until we started using SqlServer for our Session management.
Our hosting service (ITech) has a server farm so it is imperative that we get this working against SqlServer for the session management.

The issue that we are seeing is on the save of objects that were placed into session and then later retrieved. The rowstate for the objects are getting reset to invalid instead of added etc.
We contacted Entity Spaces for assistance and their advice was to use “their” serialization method to convert the objects into a string and then placing the string into the session. When we attempted this, the primary object was being serialized properly but it did not attempt to serialize any child objects in the object graph. For instance, a loan object with a list of borrowers hanging off of it. The loan itself would be serialized but not the borrowers list.

If I serialized manually to binary and store that into the session, the entire object graph is there but now we are back to the rowstate not being set properly. I decided to work around this by creating my own rowstate property called “Status”. I then would set the Status property to the objects rowstate just before I serialized to binary. Then I would flip the rowstate from invalid to whatever Status was set to when I deserialized the object. This all “looked” right in the debugger but, when I told it to save, Entity Spaces did not create the right SQL.  It tried to save without the values of the properties of the entity.

Has anyone else attempted this and if so, did you find a solution?